# TypeError when creating file with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am simply trying to make a new file with python 3.4, but whenever I try it gives me a TypeError:

```
    >>> f = open("test.txt","w")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
        f = open("test.txt","w")
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

please help, I have tried so hard to fix this but it won't

(Sorry if it's something obvious, I'm kind of new to this)

Comment: I'm guessing you have `from os import *`?

Comment: 99% chance you rebound `open` to something else.

Comment: This doesn't happen with the regular `open`, please give a [mcve].

Comment: Taken out of context, this shouldn't happen. There's some voodoo we're not seeing here.

Comment: I have tested this on Python 3.4.4 and I don't get an error (although I expected one). You are in the interactive shell, right? Try to use the full path of where you want the file to be.

Comment: Don't worry i fixed it. For anyone who stumbles upon this though:

Comment: And thank you to every one to helping

Comment: I had "from os import *" and so it was trying to use os.open() instead of the regular, which requires an integer instead of 'r', 'w', or 'x'